# Add Feature Based on Selection from a Reference Layer

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, lidar, arcgis-10.5

I have a reference grid with 11,525 features that references a repository of the same number of lidar rasters. Repository is currently a separate drive, but the location can be wherever I need it to be.

Is there a way to add features based on a selection of features in a reference layer? So, I would select grid quadrants, run a script, and the script would add the raster tiles based upon the selection.

I ask because I had an old VBA script that essentially did this based on a grid and SID tiles. Obviously understanding VBA is no longer an option and what I'd be working with is ArcPy. I have some working knowledge of ArcPy.

Or, I'm open to other workarounds which can yield greater efficiency. Much of the surface analysis we perform is area of interest-based and I would like to avoid wholesale merging all of the lidar tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a script tool could be developed that would load up the rasters based upon a selection in a feature layer. You could also explore the option of developing a "task" in ArcPro, you need only explore the help file to learn about that. Another thing you could explore as an alternative modern way of dealing with large numbers of rasters is creating a mosaic dataset and do away with selecting and load but instead have a seamless virtual layer.

Comment: I'm familiar with mosaic, but with a few dozen tiles at a time, not 11,000+. Is there a way to (no better term) "mosaic en masse"?

Comment: Just to be sure you are talking about the same thing, a "mosaic dataset" is not the same as a mosaicked dataset which is the physical joining of adjacent rasters into a single  large raster. A mosaic dataset could have thousands of rasters virtually joined.